# Best approach to converting Boolean object to string in java

Tags: java, boolean

I am trying to convert boolean to string type...

```
Boolean b = true;
String str = String.valueOf(b);
```

or

```
Boolean b = true;
String str = Boolean.toString(b);
```

which one of above would be more efficient?

Comment: Have you looked at the *source code* of these two methods?

Comment: I prefer `""+b`. Its slower but more efficient for the developer.  If you want top performance you can write the data to/from a direct ByteBuffer, i.e. change what you do with the String so you don't need it.

Comment: Also, if you want to treat `null` as `false`, you can use `String.format("%b", b)`

Answer (score 168, accepted):

I don't think there would be any significant performance difference between them, but I would prefer the 1st way.

If you have a `Boolean` reference, `Boolean.toString(boolean)` will throw `NullPointerException` if your reference is `null`. As the reference is unboxed to `boolean` before being passed to the method.

While, `String.valueOf()` method as the source code shows, does the explicit `null` check:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Just test this code:

```
Boolean b = null;

System.out.println(String.valueOf(b));    // Prints null
System.out.println(Boolean.toString(b));  // Throws NPE
```

---

For primitive boolean, there is no difference.

Answer (score 32):

If you are sure that your value is not `null` you can use third option which is

```
String str3 = b.toString();
```

and its code looks like

```
public String toString() {
    return value ? "true" : "false";
}
```

---

If you want to be null-safe use `String.valueOf(b)` which code looks like

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

so as you see it will first test for `null` and later invoke `toString()` method on your object.

---

Calling `Boolean.toString(b)` will invoke

```
public static String toString(boolean b) {
    return b ? "true" : "false";
}
```

which is little slower than `b.toString()` since JVM needs to first *unbox* `Boolean` to `boolean` which will be passed as argument to `Boolean.toString(...)`, while `b.toString()` reuses `private boolean value` field in `Boolean` object which holds its state.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Sandbox {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean b = true;
        boolean z = false;
        echo (b);
        echo (z);
        echo ("Value of b= " + b +"\nValue of z= " + z);
    }

    public static void echo(Object obj){
        System.out.println(obj);
    } 

}
```

> ```
> Result
> --------------
> true
> false
> Value of b= true
> Value of z= false
> --------------
> ```

Comment: Try to format correctly your code, and to give some explanations.

Answer (score 3):

If this is for the purpose of getting a constant "true" value, rather than "True" or "TRUE", you can use this:

```
Boolean.TRUE.toString();
Boolean.FALSE.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by "efficient". Performance-wise both versions are the same as its the same bytecode.

```
$ ./javap.exe -c java.lang.String | grep -A 10 "valueOf(boolean)"
  public static java.lang.String valueOf(boolean);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: ifeq          9
       4: ldc           #14                 // String true
       6: goto          11
       9: ldc           #10                 // String false
      11: areturn


$ ./javap.exe -c java.lang.Boolean | grep -A 10 "toString(boolean)"
  public static java.lang.String toString(boolean);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: ifeq          9
       4: ldc           #3                  // String true
       6: goto          11
       9: ldc           #2                  // String false
      11: areturn
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a quick way to do this, for example debugging, you can simply concatenate an empty string on to the boolean:

```
System.out.println(b+"");
```

However, I strongly recommend using another method for production usage. This is a simple quick solution which is useful for debugging.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you don't recommend using for production usage? Can it fail in some scenario?

Comment: @lazyvab In all honesty I have no idea! I don't write Java anymore but I can only presumable it was something I must have heard. I've been programming in other languages for the past few years but can't see why using this in production would hurt. Besides `System.out.println` is for debugging anyway, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you see implementation of both the method, they look same.

**String.valueOf(b)**

```
public static String valueOf(boolean b) {
        return b ? "true" : "false";
    }
```

**Boolean.toString(b)**

```
public static String toString(boolean b) {
        return b ? "true" : "false";
    }
```

So both the methods are equally efficient.