# Shouldn't catch NPE but don't know how to handle the NULL

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I know that NPE is not recommended to be caught, however the NPE is in a method whose return value is a boolean based on the variable where the NPE comes from.

Code is something like this:

```
public static boolean isStale() {
 return a.get();  //a==null causing NPE
}
```

In my case, I don't really know what to return without the info of a. 
What should I do? What kind of exception should I throw, if any?

Edit:
1. returning true or false will be inaccurate because the result really depends on the info inside a.

2. a is acctually from a service call client.getA()

Comment: Why is `a` allowed to be `null` at this point if you don't want to handle it ? An exceptio is a healthy behaviour for unexpected inputs

Comment: Don't catch the NPE (it's a programming bug on the violated invariant/caller) *or* do something useful when `a` is null. Perhaps return false (after a check for null)? If `a` being null is a different kind of caller violation but *not* an invariant violation - i.e "a is closed" - then there may be a different kind of exception to throw; but this depends on what a "null a" means.

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason why you should prevent your code from throwing exceptions. Just consider your case : you say yourself that the behaviour of your method is not defined in the case `a == null`, so why should you handle it ? It will only lead to weird behaviours and your users might be surprised that their code failed or produce unexpected results somewhere whereas their calls into your API went fine.

Exceptions are specially designed to address this kind of things, so make good use of it. You can either throw a new, custom exception to add some API-specific semantic, or let the NPE be propagated to the caller.

For example :

```
public static boolean isStale() {
     if (a == null) throw new IllegalStateException("a should not be null");
     return a.get();
}
```

However, it is more likely that you should do that in a constructor (because I assume `a` is an attribute). In a constructor, I would opt for `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I think this is the solution to my problem.  Either let NPE progagate or throw custom exception so that the users of my API know something unexpected happened.  Thanks!

Comment: Where is `a` constructed ? Usually you try to throw NPE as soon as possible ie in the constructors

Comment: a is actually a Map<String, String>

Comment: The type is not important, I'm just asking where it is constructed. Is it an attribute of the class containing this method ?

Comment: a is a field of an object obtain from a service call.

Comment: Well anyway, check if it's null as soon as possible, usually in a constructor

Answer (score 1):

First you need to ask yourself: Is it normal for `a` to ever be `null`?

If `yes`, then throwing an exception is rarely a good idea.  Exceptions should really only be thrown when something unexpected occurs. It then really is up to you to decide what this means for your program.  Does it make sense to return some default value in this case?

```
return a == null ? false : a.get(); // return false as a default value?
```

If `no` (more likely):

... then ask the following question: ***Why*** am I getting a `null` value?

If it's because you coded a bug: then you don't need to do anything.  Just let it throw a `NullPointerException`. There really is no point in catching the exception and pretending everything is alright, if clearly, a basic invariant in your program has been broken.  Better to let it throw the exception early and focus your energies on understanding and fixing the bug asap.  Trying to handle the exception will only cause your program to fail at some other more unexpected point in time, and will become that much harder to debug.

If, on the other hand, it's because of some external entity feeding you bad data over which you really have no control: then this could be a good case for throwing a custom exception that can be used to provide a more meaningful error message to either the user or the developer.  But even in this case, it's probably a better idea to have `a` validated for a `null` value more "upstream" and have it throw an exception as early as possible.  It doesn't feel like it should be part of the `isStale()` method's contract to worry about the correctness of `a`'s value.

---

Interesting reading, geared towards C#, but the principles apply just as well to Java: [Vexing exceptions](http://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to throw any Exception just **make sure** `a` isn't `null` before using it, use a simple conditional statement:

```
public static boolean isStale() {
  a!=null ? return a.get() : return false;  
}
```

In the case where returning false will be irrelevant, you can just change the return type of your method to String and return a warning or any other significant message :

```
public static String isStale() {
  a!=null ? return a.get().toString() : return "NULL";  
}
```

Take a look at this: **[Best approach to converting Boolean object to string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833054/best-approach-to-converting-boolean-object-to-string-in-java)**

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what isStale() determines. You can try/catch this method and catch the NullPointerException. I don't believe this violates best practices if you really have no way to handle `a` being null. You could also instantiate a new `a` if `a` is null, or throw your own Exception.