# How to convert boolean (true or false) to string value in groovy?

Tags: groovy, casting, boolean

```
def setOnePlueOne(def user, def booleanValue) {
    updateAnswerAttribute(userRandy, ??????)
    ...
}
```

so what I have to do to convert that `boolean` to string and `updateAnswerAttribute` as `true` or `false` in DB.

Added getter and setter:

```
public Boolean setOnePlueOne() {
    return OnePlueOne;
}
public void getOnePlueOne(Boolean onePlueOne) {
    this.onePlueOne = onePlueOne;
```

Now, I need to convert that (`Boolean onePlueOne`) in string (`true` or `false`) and send it through set method to `def booleanValue`:

```
def setOnePlueOne(def user, def booleanValue) {
    updateAnswerAttribute(userRandy, ??????) 
    ...
}
```

this will update or create value in DB.

Answer (score 19):

The two best ways of doing this are :

1. `String.valueOf(booleanValue)`
2. `Boolean.toString(booleanValue)`

Though the preferred is the first one as second gives null pointer when booleanValue = null.

[Best approach to converting Boolean object to string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833054/best-approach-to-converting-boolean-object-to-string-in-java)

Comment: `second gives null pointer`... Did you mean `the second gives a null pointer Exception`?  What I observe is that the first returns null and the second throws an exception when booleanValue == null.

Answer (score 6):

Use `toString()` method of any `Boolean`, e.g.:

```
Boolean flag = true
String value = flag.toString()
```