# convert boolean to string

Tags: java, android

I have app to check app is installed or not and used this boolean

```
 final boolean b1 = appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");

.....


 private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }
}
```

I want to convert the boolean to string and get the correct value. I tried this but if I want to delete app, get an error "don't find package"

```
 String str = String.valueOf(b1);
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error you're getting, including the stacktrace?

Comment: error inside app.. if click button to uninstall.. this means the way use for convert is wrong because if use Strings direct work fine

Comment: Why exactly do you need to convert the boolean to a string? You did not indicate what you need the string for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best approach to converting Boolean object to string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833054/best-approach-to-converting-boolean-object-to-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
String booleanString = Boolean.toString(boolValue)
```

Comment: i try this also .. same problem

Answer (score 1):

```
   This is how you can modify your approach 

            PackageInfo pinfo;

            try {
                pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("Your package name", 0);
            } 
            catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {   
                pinfo = null;
            }

            if(pinfo!=null)
              {
               **"Installed"**
              }
            else
               {
               "Not Installed"
               }
```

---

I don't understand why you approached so, this will give to the best result.
Check this. This is how we compare our package with a package in playstore.

```
public String getSignature(String pkgName) throws NameNotFoundException {
            PackageInfo pi = pkgMngr.getPackageInfo(pkgName, GET_SIGNATURES);
        String signature = pi.signatures[0].toCharsString();
        return signature;
    } 

    public boolean doSignaturesMatch(String pkg1, String pkg2) {
        boolean match = pkgMngr.checkSignatures(pkg1, pkg2) == SIGNATURE_MATCH;
        return match;
    } 

    public boolean isInstalledFromMarket(String pkgName)
            throws NameNotFoundException { 
        String installerPkg = pkgMngr.getInstallerPackageName(pkgName);
        boolean installedFromMarket = "com.google.android.feedback"
                .equals(installerPkg);
```

---